# open JMX through jconsole on Remote WildFly 21 server

Tags: wildfly, jmx, jconsole, wildfly-21

I am trying to connect to Wildfly 21 JMX through jconsole. Did the below steps

1. created management user(admin)
2. opened jconsole.bat from wildfly/bin directory
3. tried with service:jmx:remote+http://wildfly_host_ip_address:9990

Getting the following error. What am i missing?

[image: jconsole error]

JMX subsystem configuration

[image: JMX subsystem]

Comment: Do you have port 9990 listening on that host? By default it will only be using localhost.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, yes it is through socket-binding and all interfaces are updated to the ipaddress.
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>

Comment: So you've got the `management` interface listening on the IP address of your host? When I just did `./bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement=0.0.0.0` I was able to remotely connect.

Comment: -bmanagement=0.0.0.0 in the startup script did the trick but adding ipaddress to management interface on standalone-full-ha.xml didn't work. Thank you very much James

Comment: Can you share the JVM options you set (e.g. -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0 etc...) ?

Comment: @Sumanth, did you get any solution?

Comment: @Sumanth, please suggest a solution, getting error on configuraing jmx subsystem  in standalone.xml, Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]"]